# Hide a widget's internal build in the tree but show in the Widget Detail Tree

Tags: flutter

if you take a look at the Flutter Inspector you can see the WidgetTree. If you click a Widget you can also see the detailed Widget Tree.

For Flutter Widgets like the Scaffold, you can only see "Scaffold" in the Widget tree. If you click that one and check the detailed tree you can actually see which other widgets are used to build the Scaffold.

Can we use the same mechanic for our own Widgets?
For some Widgets I'm only interested that they are in the WidgetTree, but I don't need to see any other widget it uses to build itself.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector#track-widget-creation

Comment: @huytc I don't think so, I can not see where I can hide my own widget tree.

Comment: According to the article, if you create a StatefulWidget/StatelessWidget class for your widget (instead of returning your widget from a normal function), the default behavior of the inspector should be to hide your widget tree.